# Why doesn't tasks -V list plugins from .sbt global directory?

Tags: sbt

Why are the plugins defined in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` not included in `sbt tasks -V` list?

```
jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/project
[info] Set current project to scalania (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/}scalania 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform, org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2

jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ sbt 'tasks -V idea'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/project
[info] Set current project to scalania (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
No matches for regular expression 'idea'.

jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ sbt 'tasks -V' | grep -i idea
```

The `gen-idea` task of the sbt-idea plugin works perfectly fine.

```
jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ sbt gen-idea
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/project
[info] Set current project to scalania (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/scalania/)
[info] Creating IDEA module for project 'scalania' ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Creating IDEA module for project 'answers' ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Creating IDEA module for project 'exercises' ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Excluding folder target
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea/IdeaProject.iml
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea
[info] Excluding folder /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/target
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea_modules/scalania.iml
[info] Excluding folder /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/answers/target
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea_modules/answers.iml
[info] Excluding folder /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/exercises/target
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea_modules/exercises.iml
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea_modules/scalania-build.iml
[info] Created /Users/jacek/oss/scalania/.idea_modules/exercises-build.iml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gen-idea` is a command, not a task.  You should see it in the output of `help idea`.

Comment: How do I find out the complete list of commands for a given project? How could I know about `gen-idea` without reading the docs of the plugin?

Comment: As I couldn't get what I wanted with `help idea`, I've asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/19477010/1305344 (so the real answer is not burried in comments).