# How to know available commands (=named operations) in sbt

Tags: sbt

I use sbt `0.13.1`.

To list the tasks in a [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) project, one can use `sbt tasks -V`.

As [A "command" looks similar to a task: it's a named operation that can be executed from the sbt console](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html) and [Typically, you would resort to a command when you need to do something that's impossible in a regular task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html), how can I know what commands are available for a sbt project?

Is there a similar command to list all of the commands in a sbt project?

Say, the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin's installed in a sbt project. How could I query the project to find out about [the `gen-idea` command](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea#basic-project)?

It's so confusing given the comment of [@Mark Harrah](https://stackoverflow.com/u/850196): ["gen-idea is a command, not a task."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460030/1305344) and the documentation of the `sbt-idea` plugin where it says ["Use the gen-idea sbt task to create Idea project files."](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea#basic-project) (note the use of **task**). I am confused.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't "help" without any arguments do that? From my understanding "tasks" without any arguments will list available tasks and "help" w/o arguments will do a similar things for commands.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You could use `commands` to see the available commands for a project, but it doesn't give you their names, just stringified (`toString`) version. I've just noticed that `sbt.SimpleCommand` is private and it may be impossible to develop a command to list the commands. I do hope I'm mistaken.

Comment: The command to list commands is already developed- it is `help`.  Commands have full flexibility in their syntax, so they must provide help.  Many of the Command constructors have ways of specifying this help.  It appears that sbt-idea doesn't provide help so it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue it's an implementation detail.

Do you have a real use case where you require to list only commands? :-)

--
Update 1:

```
sbt
$ <tab><tab>
Display all 339 possibilities? (y or n) [y]
# ... 
gen-idea
# ...
```

Simply tabbing in the terminal gives you all actions you can perform, including gen-idea - your use-case.

Comment: New users in a project would like to know what they can do. Tasks have tasks command, but since gen-idea is not a task it's not listed anywhere. Is this enough to be a real use case?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think it's in the session to find out about available commands. Your solution still requires to "parse" the output. I'd love being able to query for the tasks of a given plugin. If no one offers another answer soon, I'd accept yours. Thanks!